# Blur from OpenCV in Region of Interest

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying create a circle and blur the contents in OpenCV. However, I am able to make the circle, but I am not able to blur that part. My code is given below. Please help me out

```
import io
import picamera
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
from time import sleep
from PIL import ImageFilter


image = cv2.imread('/home/pi/Desktop/cricle-test/output_0020.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/Desktop/Image-Detection-test/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.2,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30),
    flags = cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
)
print "Found {0} faces!".format(len(faces))

# Draw a circle around the faces and blur
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

    sub = cv2.circle(image, ( int((x + x + w )/2), int((y + y + h)/2 )), int (h / 2), (0, 255, 0), 5)
    cv2.blur(image(x,y,w,h),(23,23), 40000)
    cv2.imwrite("/home/pi/Desktop/cricle-test/output_0020.jpg" ,image)
```

Comment: I would suggest reading the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#blur).... not sure what is your 40000 there but it should be the destination, in other words, where you want to write the result. You are doing it but not writing it anywhere. Maybe this gives the correct result `image(x,y,w,h) = cv2.blur(image(x,y,w,h),(23,23))`.

Comment: 4000 is blur value. which is showing blur level. lemme try your code will get back to you soon.

Comment: i tried your code but it is blurring whole image rather than cirlce.

Comment: There is no blur value in blur, you probably are thinkning about [gaussianBlur](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#gaussianblur) function which has sigma values. try with `image[y:y+h, x:x+w] = cv2.blur(image[y:y+h, x:x+w] ,(23,23))` this will get the slice of the image... notice the y first, in OpenCV is (y,x) in the image index (point tuples are x,y).

Comment: thanks, but it is not blurring the circle it is adding a square frame  over the circle.i want to cut it into circle. this is my main motive.

Comment: well you had it as a square, so I fixed to do the same square... anyways for a circle is a little bit more complicated, you can do it with a mask. I will write a complete answer in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For it to work you need to do a couple of things, first `cv2.blur` needs a destination and not a number. This can be achieved with:

```
image[y:y+h, x:x+w] = cv2.blur(image[y:y+h, x:x+w] ,(23,23))
```

Since you are saving the image to the same file in every loop, you can just save it after the loop.

Since you wanted a circular bur, you need to create a circular mask, then apply it to the image, here is how your code will look like (only the loop part):

```
# create a temp image and a mask to work on
tempImg = image.copy()
maskShape = (image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 1)
mask = np.full(maskShape, 0, dtype=np.uint8)
# start the face loop
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
  #blur first so that the circle is not blurred
  tempImg [y:y+h, x:x+w] = cv2.blur(tempImg [y:y+h, x:x+w] ,(23,23))
  # create the circle in the mask and in the tempImg, notice the one in the mask is full
  cv2.circle(tempImg , ( int((x + x + w )/2), int((y + y + h)/2 )), int (h / 2), (0, 255, 0), 5)
  cv2.circle(mask , ( int((x + x + w )/2), int((y + y + h)/2 )), int (h / 2), (255), -1)

# oustide of the loop, apply the mask and save
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image,mask = mask_inv)
img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(tempImg,tempImg,mask = mask)
dst = cv2.add(img1_bg,img2_fg)

cv2.imwrite("/home/pi/Desktop/cricle-test/output_0020.jpg" ,dst)
```

This seems to work, at least in my test, you may try adjusting the kernel size (this (23,23) in the blur) to get less or more blurred image, for example, try this code with (7,7) it will have more details.

## Update

If you want to use ellipses instead of circles just change the circle instruction to:

```
cv2.ellipse(mask , ( ( int((x + x + w )/2), int((y + y + h)/2 )),(w,h), 0), 255, -1)
```

The same way you can change it to a rectangle, polygon, or any other shape.

Comment: @Pulkit if you find it helpful and solves your problem, mark it as the answer or vote it up, for other people with similar problem to find the solution faster :)

Comment: one more thing Api55 that i wanna remove green outline. can you help me with this?

Comment: @Pulkit that comes from the first cv2.circle instruction, the one that actually draws a the circle. Remove that line and it should not appear anymore. The line that starts with `cv2.circle(tempImg , ......`.

Comment: and what should i do if wanna change circle to ellipse?

Comment: how can i increase the area of ellipse because now i am blurring eye ? and i have x,y,w,h of eyes only so i want to increase the area.

Comment: just increase rectangles (x,y,w,h), if you increase w and h it will be bigger but the corner (top left) in the same position if you decrease x and y and increase w and h the ellipse/rectangle will be bigger

Comment: My current code is this :actually i wanna blur face whenever i got eyes: `for (x, y, w, h) in eyes:
     tempImg [y:y+h+y+x+h, x:x+w+x+y+w] = cv2.blur(tempImg [y:y+h+y+x+h, x:x+w+x+y+w] ,(47,47))
     cv2.ellipse(mask , ( ( int((x + x + w )/2), int((y + y + h)/2 )),(w*6,h*6), 0), 255, -1)`

Comment: @Pulkit is better to ask a new question with all these details, so that you get a better answer from me or from someone else

Comment: ok but i am not allowed to ask question before next five days. so can i send my my code through mail?

Comment: i tried increasing rectangles coordinates but then it is difficult to find centre of ellipse.

Comment: just decrease x, y by half amount that you increase w,h. Then the center will be calculated by the same algorithm. For example if you want to make it 20 pixels bigger in width and 30 in height, x-10, y-15, w+20, h +30 should do the trick. this will preserve the same center as before but increasing the size