# How can ı blur detected object (YoloV5)?

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, yolov5

I trained a custom yolov5 model and i want to blur detected objects. How can i do it?

```
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='yolov5/runs/train/exp6/weights/last.pt', force_reload=True)
img = os.path.join("uc.jpg")
results = model(img)

%matplotlib inline 
plt.imshow(np.squeeze(results.render()))
plt.show()
```

[object detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14E84.png)

```
results.xyxy[0]
results.pandas().xyxy[0]
```

the coordinats

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhgkp.png)

Comment: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic]

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46886742/18667225